# Question on how does `date` command in busybox work well with Y2038 fix

Tags: c, linux, datetime, busybox

I am working on an embedded Linux system (5.10.24) which has fixed Y2038.
I did following tests in target system (with busybox 1.36), and got puzzled on the tests.

1. I ran `date -s "2038-01-19 03:14:10"`, it worked fine with fix of Y2038 (I added printf in `date_main()` to show the `tv_sec` got from `time()` called).
2. I ran `date` then, I can read the right date and time.
3. I wrote a C program did the *same* thing as `date_main` does in busybox, and ran it in target to get the date and time, but I got wrong data.

Here comes the log.

```
#
# date -s "2038-01-19 03:14:10"
tm.year: 138, tm.mon: 0, tm.mday: 19
tm.year: 138, tm.mon: 0, tm.mday: 19
Tue Jan 19 03:14:10 UTC 2038
#
# date && sleep 2 && date
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2139132224
tm.year: 138, tm.mon: 0, tm.mday: 19
tm.year: 138, tm.mon: 0, tm.mday: 19
Tue Jan 19 03:14:16 UTC 2038
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2142846048
tm.year: 138, tm.mon: 0, tm.mday: 19
tm.year: 138, tm.mon: 0, tm.mday: 19
Tue Jan 19 03:14:18 UTC 2038
#
#
# /tmp/timedate
And: Sat Sep 24 01:41:40 UTC 2033
Asciitime: 24:8:133
```

From the logs there were 2 things strange.

1. `date && sleep 2 && date` called date 2 times, I assumed the `tv_sec` returned should be correct with 2 seconds. But they are NOT.
2. my program of `timedate` followed the *SAME* logic as `date_main()` of busybox to get date and time, but the date shown is totally wrong.

Here is my change to `date_main()` in busybox.

```
259         memset(&ts, 0, sizeof(ts));  /// Added
260         time(&ts.tv_sec);
261         printf("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX %ld\n", ts.tv_sec);  /// Added.
```

Here is my timedate.c,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define  COMMON_BUFSIZE  128

int main()
{
    struct timeval  tv;
    char buf_fmt_dt2str[64];
    char date_buf[128] = {0};
    char *fmt_dt2str = buf_fmt_dt2str;
    struct tm tm_time;

    time(&tv.tv_sec);

    localtime_r(&tv.tv_sec, &tm_time);
    fmt_dt2str = (char*)"%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y";
    strftime(date_buf, COMMON_BUFSIZE, fmt_dt2str, &tm_time);
    printf("And: %s\n", date_buf);
    printf("Asciitime: %d:%d:%d\n", tm_time.tm_mday, tm_time.tm_mon, tm_time.tm_year);

    return 0;
}
```

I am puzzled *COMPLETELY* with the testing result.

Comment: You need to print `tm_time.tm_mon + 1` and `tm_time.tm_year + 1900`.

Comment: Which C runtime libraries are you using? For Glibc, you may need to compile your program with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_TIME_BITS=64` to get 64-bit `time_t` on a 32-bit system.

Comment: The glibc is 2.35 which should be built with Y2038 fix. I will try these 2 options later. But I got confused on the values `time()` returned in sequence, they are NOT in increased order, and with those `incorrect` tv_sec, how can `date_main()` return the right date and time.....

Comment: You can confirm with `printf("sizeof(time_t)=%zu\n", sizeof(time_t));`, which should print `8` for 64-bit `time_t`.

Comment: My checked my timedate.c, it is built without 64bit options, so the size of time_t is 4. I still don't understand why `time()` in `date_main()` can get the right date time. I will try that later.

Comment: Normally, `tv_sec` only has to store values in the range 0..60 (leap seconds).  It won’t be big enough to hold 64-bit `time_t` values.  Store the result of `time()` in a `time_t` variable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good point for the `tm_sec` member of `struct tm`, but this `tv_sec` is a member of `struct timeval` and has type `time_t` (otherwise `&tv.tv_sec` would be incompatible with the parameter of `time()`).

Comment: @IanAbbott: Oh — `tm_sec` vs `tv_sec` — yes, my bad!  'Tis curious to use the `struct timeval` type when you never use `tv_usec` element.  I normally write something along the lines of `time_t t = time(0);` rather than `time_t t; time(&t);`.  The argumentative form of `time()` is a relic from the days transitioning between 16-bit and 32-bit `int` types, in the late 70s or early 80s.

Comment: In your changes to busybox, `printf("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX %ld\n", ts.tv_sec);` should be something like `printf("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX %lld\n", (long long)ts.tv_sec);` in case `time_t` is wider than `long`.

Comment: @IanAbbott, you are right. I compiled my timedate.c with -D_TIME_BITS=64 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64, it can get and show the right time and date as busybox. You can post your comments as the answer.